# Show $ T_1'= < V,(E_1\setminus \{ e_1 \}) \cup \{ e_2 \} > $ , $ T_2' = < V,(E_2\setminus \{ e_2 \}) \cup \{ e_1 \} > $ are both trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Problem:** Let $ G $ be a connected graph, simple and finite. Let $ T_1 = \langle V,E_1 \rangle ,\ T_2 = \langle V,E_2\rangle $ be trees s.t. $ E_1, E_2 \subseteq E $. Show that for every edge $ e_1 \in E_1 \setminus E_2 $ there exists an edge $ e_2 \in E_2 \setminus E_1 $ s.t.
$ T_1' =  \langle V,(E_1\setminus \{ e_1 \}) \cup \{ e_2 \} \rangle  ~~~~~$ , $ T_2' =  \langle V,(E_2\setminus \{ e_2 \}) \cup \{ e_1 \} \rangle  ~~~~$, are both trees.

**Attempt** - I am stuck at this problem for hours, couldn't make any progress. Still, here's what I've done :
Let $ e_1 \in E_1 \setminus E_2 $ be arbitrary. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $ \forall $ $ e_2 \in E_2 \setminus E_1 $,  $ T_1' =  \langle V,(E_1\setminus \{ e_1 \}) \cup \{ e_2 \} \rangle ~~~ $ OR $ ~~~~ T_2' =  \langle V,(E_2\setminus \{ e_2 \}) \cup \{ e_1 \} \rangle  $ aren't trees.
Let $ e_2 \in E_2 \setminus E_1 $ be arbitrary, then  $ T_1' =  \langle V,(E_1\setminus \{ e_1 \}) \cup \{ e_2 \} \rangle ~~~ $ OR $ ~~~~ T_2' = \langle V,(E_2\setminus \{ e_2 \}) \cup \{ e_1 \} \rangle  $ aren't trees. We'll show that $ T_1' $ is connected or has simple circuits and we'll also show that $ T_2' $ is connected or has simple circuits ( so that we'll reach contradiction for both ). [ From here I don't know what else to do ]

I feel lost. I'd appreciate if you can please help me.